# can't install software--can I fix missing dpkg?

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management, dpkg

> New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair now?

hit `Repair`

```
Package operation failed 
The installation or removal of a software package failed.
Details => installArchives()failed:Could not exec dpkg!
Error in function

(synaptic:12725): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
sh: 1: dpkg: not found
```

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install -f`, post the error message.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  skype
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 62.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
tom@thomas:~$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
mkdir /tmp/dpkg
cd /tmp/dpkg
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_i386.deb
# or
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb
ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz
tar xvzf data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

Comment: I don't understand very much of coding, but I would like to know what is been doing with that code lines. I have the same problem (`g_child_watch_add_full`) and I want to be a little more informed to take my decision for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @pedro-sardinha-u94410: You should use the command man. man sudo - man mkdir - man wget - man ar - man tar - man cp - man apt-get.