# Can't use apt: libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, dpkg

When I use apt I have problems:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
apt-get: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by apt-get) apt-get: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
```

However, installing new apt outputs:

```
dpkg: regarding .../apt_1.2.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb containing apt:
apt breaks apt-utils (<< 1.1.3)
apt-utils (version 1.0.1ubuntu2) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /home/anawasreh/Downloads/apt_1.2.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 installing apt would break apt-utils, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/anawasreh/Downloads/apt_1.2.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb
(13:13:21)anawasreh@readonly@anawasreh(-)
```

Even if I try to download the missing lib:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6

apt-get: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
`GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by apt-get) apt-get:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not
found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
```

So I'm stuck there and can't remove, update, or correct apt at all.

Comment: How were you installing new apt? by downloading the deb file?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/474646/cant-install-software-can-i-fix-missing-dpkg

Answer (score 3):

You could copy `libstdc++.so.6` from another Ubuntu installation.

In a 14.04 virtual machine, I removed `libstdc++.so.6` and got the same error as you. Then I copied it from my 16.04 host, and `apt` worked again. You could use a Live CD for this.

Alternatively, download the the right file for your version:

**14.04**: https://bsre.stackstorage.com/index.php/s/JVNxNO3HWBA4HSa
**16.04**: https://bsre.stackstorage.com/index.php/s/L394ttygh55cR1W

Then open a Terminal window using <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

1. Type `cd ~/Downloads` and press enter
2. Type `md5sum libstdc++*` and press enter
3. Make sure you see either of the following:

   `aa688ac2f4c90a023c2cbd1dd21d4ccc  libstdc++1404.so.6`
   `68dbd855c3213cae1a41375c25bf6884  libstdc++1604.so.6`
4. Then rename the file using `sudo mv libstdc++* libstdc++.so.6`
5. Move the file: `sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: There is another error now:
[~/Downloads]>apt-get update
apt-get: symbol lookup error: apt-get: undefined symbol: _ZN13pkgSrcRecords6Parser6Files2ERSt6vectorINS_5File2ESaIS2_EE

Comment: @Aladdin I forgot to ask what architecture you're using. What does `uname -m` give you?

Comment: it is x86_64 ..

Comment: @Aladdin And what does `lsb_release -a` output in the description part?

Comment: The output is
[~]>lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Answer (score 0):

This was little complicated, I dont remember what exactly I had done when I had this problem.

Maybe this can help:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```

This may not work if you dont have python software properties installed.

So,try updating your repositories and PPAs to default. follow this link to know how to do it: [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Can't use apt-get
sudo apt-get update
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: invalid ELF header

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem earlier. I fixed it by downloading libstdc++6 debian package from [here](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/270880798/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1_i386.deb) and later did a manual install using 'dpkg'

```
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1_i386.deb
```

After this it apt was working fine