# Apt not working properly

Tags: 16.04, apt

I recently did some library installs manually 
one of them is

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb 

dpkg: warning: downgrading libstdc++6:amd64 from 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4 to 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
(Reading database ... 268816 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libstdc++6_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) over (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6:amd64:
 libstdc++6:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1); however:
  Package gcc-4.8-base is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++6:amd64
```

After this whenever i try any command with apt it gives me the following error

```
$ sudo apt update 

apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
```

Comment: Here's a similar question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/826475/cant-use-apt-command-or-install-a-new-one Have you tried any of the suggestions there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use apt command or install a new one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826475/cant-use-apt-command-or-install-a-new-one)

Comment: thanks @Melebius for the edit and yeah it also looks like a similar problem