# Ubuntu 20.04 black screen on boot

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, libraries

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and having dual boot.

While uninstalling the `gcc` package, I mistakenly uninstalled `ubuntu-desktop` and `libstdc++.so.6` packages. Now I am facing this black screen when I boot on *Try Ubuntu*.

I tried with Ubuntu recovery option. In there, I tried giving the broken package in `dpkg`, but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/disc-packages/DistUpgrade/disp-upgrade.py", line 3, in <module>
    from DistUpgradeMain import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/disc-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 22, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/disc-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: libstdC++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Re-install

Is this a brand new or recent install? The simplest thing would be to backup your user data from terminal and install ubuntu from scratch.

I think the installer would also detect that there is an older version and offer to keep user data (only the home directories) when doing a reinstall from a disk, an image(for virtual machines) or USB.

**This would be the simplest solution.**

## Download libstdC++.so.6 Debian Package

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/925749/214509), you could possibly download the Debian package and do a manual install:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/270880798/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1_i386.deb
```

Then reboot. The `apt` command should be working and you could reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` package.

## Copy the library from another Ubuntu install

This is what I would have done as I always have multiple systems with Ubuntu runing in my house. I will let you read on the details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/826482/214509).

**Hope you find a solution!**

Comment: thank you soo much!!! :) ;) ;)