# How to reinstall dpkg

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, configuration

I always get this error when I attempt to install a package using `apt-get`. I would appreciate help. This seems a common problem with every other package, but I've never encountered a problem with the `dpkg` itself.

[image]

Comment: the apt-get -f install prompts the same message

Comment: Recover some backups of dpkg:
`sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Can't find a source to download version '1.17.5ubuntu5.4' of 'dpkg:amd64'

Comment: Please update & add output from command: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`
Have you tried using `Synaptic`/`Aptitude` to reinstall packages.

Answer (score 3):

### [**Ubuntu `dpkg` recovery**](http://staff.adams.edu/%7Ecdmiller/posts/Ubuntu-dpkg-recovery/)

**Recover `dpkg` status file**

```
cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Reinstall - `dpkg`**

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/ 
dpkg --force-depends -i dpkg_*.deb
```

**Reinstall - `apt`**

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
dpkg --force-depends -i apt_*.deb
dpkg --force-depends -i apt-utils_*.deb
apt-get update
```

---

**Missing files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`?**

Use `dpkg` to list installed packages..

```
dpkg -l | grep ii
```

Reinstall from output using `apt`...

```
dpkg -l | grep ii | awk '{print "apt-get --reinstall -y install", $2}' > /tmp/reinstall
```

Now, install `ucf` which may be of importance to installation of kernel or others...

```
apt-get --reinstall install ucf
```

---

Source:

- [Ubuntu Dpkg Recovery](http://staff.adams.edu/%7Ecdmiller/posts/Ubuntu-dpkg-recovery/)

Comment: it still has the same error despite all the commands listed.

Comment: "The package dpkg needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." >> exact error listed

Comment: for the command `cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status` , I am getting error,  `cp: cannot stat '/var/backups/dpkg.status.0': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for a user with a related problem...

```
sudo -i    
mkdir /tmp/dpkg    
cd /tmp/dpkg

#i386 version
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.1_i386.deb    

or

#amd64 version
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb    

ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz    
tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg    
sudo cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

Source:

- [can't install software--can I fix missing dpkg?](https://askubuntu.com/a/474681/562148)

Comment: the dpkg package is no longer valid i guess? the wget returns a not found

Comment: What does `w/` mean to a learner, please use full english words and not short hands!

Comment: since you use wget to download the package to reinstall it, then you don't need to navigate to tmp where its stored temporary after installing it

Comment: You're right, @George! My bad, friend!

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg  >> gives me the same error because apt-get requires dpkg but then dpkg is the one i need to reinstall..

Comment: This answer seems to be outright plagiarised from [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/474681/759929), but actively modified so that it doesn't actually work.

Comment: @[Michael Homer](https://askubuntu.com/users/759929/michael-homer); I added the source to the bottom of my post.  Also what do you recommend I do to fix this answer?

Comment: I have re-proposed the edit; I don't have any other recommendation other than that honesty is the best policy.