# Sudo apt command not found

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am in a big problem. Everything was running ok, then I tried to install MongoDB, I was getting `dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: statoverride file contains empty line` errors and was not able to install MongoDB. By mistake, I run `sudo apt remove dpkg`. After that, no Linux commands are getting run. I am worried if my `WSL ubuntu 18.04` is crashed. How can I recover this issue? I don't want to lose any work files. Please help.

Edit:
When I run the command `sudo apt remove dpkg` after some time, it opened a screen asking `OK` or `CANCEL`. I did not understand and I close the terminal directly. So, I am really not getting what exactly happened. After that, I cannot run `sudo apt` like commands.

Comment: `apt` is a wrapper that uses `dpkg` to install packages, so if you removed `dpkg` you should not expect tools that use it to work (eg. `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` etc).  Restoration of backups may be best, but `dpkg` should not impact other commands, just the *deb* package install programs won't be able to install/remove etc.   (`dpkg` can't download packages, so `apt` and front-end tools give the simpler tools greater functionality, calling the base programs to do the work as required)

Comment: So can I restore the `dpkg` package?

Comment: Reinstall dpkg. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/878887/how-to-reinstall-dpkg

Comment: The commands to reinstall `dpkg` also gives errors. Like for the command `cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status` gives `cp: cannot stat '/var/backups/dpkg.status.0': No such file or directory`

Comment: The "how to reinstall dpkg" reference is a corrupted `dpkg` and not a removed `dpkg`, however the second (1 upvote currently) example better suits your condition (as it re-installs rather than fixed a corrupted `dpkg` as the most upvoted answer does); but you'll of course need to adapt that (which was for a now-outdated *xenial* and not your *bionic*)

Comment: The problem is for re-installing, `grep` command is needed. In my case: `./configure: line 1649: grep: command not found`

Comment: So get `grep` too (why I suggested backups).  You can explore you `apt` history (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) to see what you removed, and what you need to re-install as well (or did you `purge` and not `remove`?  .. depends rules may have meant you removed a number of packages that needed `dpkg`).  FYI: It's best if you add additional details to your question (you can edit your own questions) as details are easier to read there, and more people will see it, and don't hit "Y" (or yes; esp. '-y') to do it, until you've assessed the damage of commands

Comment: Please check the Edit.