# Facing issues with upgrading and new packages installation; dpkg returns error

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I have 18.04.1 system. I have tried upgrading packages with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but it returns an error code 2

```
/usr/bin/dpkg: 1: /usr/bin/dpkg: ��S����������
                                            ��_����������g����������
                                                                        ��_���������
                                                                                        $�_��������: not found  
/usr/bin/dpkg: 2: /usr/bin/dpkg: ��_���������������������
                                                         : not found  
/usr/bin/dpkg: 3: /usr/bin/dpkg: ��_��������: not found  
/usr/bin/dpkg: 4: /usr/bin/dpkg: �
                              
                               �_��������O�N��������_�
                                                           1
                                                            d�_���������������������
                                                                                        F
                                                                                         ��_����������
                                                                                                        @: not found   
/usr/bin/dpkg: 5: /usr/bin/dpkg: Syntax error: "(" unexpected    
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (2)    
E: Couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg states
```

I have tried many suggested solutions which contains commands like

```
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt-get -f install  
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

but any command related to dpkg ends with similar output.

Comment: looks like your `dpkg` executable might got corrupted somehow. It could be worth a try to replace it using the method described here: https://askubuntu.com/q/474646/367990 - however, you should also investigate the reason how and why it got corrupted, possibly your hard disk is about to die. Check its SMART status and self test results.

Comment: Thanks. SMART status is normal but now I am unable to boot up system. So reinstalling Ubuntu.