# Fixing dependency issues (lots of them)

Tags: command-line, dependencies

Ok, I can't seem to install anything using apt; not even aptitude, it hangs up and can't fix them for me there are so many. I installed snort by compiling it from source (but they had a lot of picky dependencies): Here is what I get when I try to install something using apt:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: perl:any
 apache2-bin : Depends: perl:any
 autoconf : Depends: perl (> 5.005) but it is not going to be installed
 autopoint : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 casper : Depends: lzma
 cli-common : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 dash : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.19.1) but it is not going to be installed
 debconf : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
 debhelper : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.18.0~) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: perl:any
 dh-autoreconf : Depends: perl:any
 dh-strip-nondeterminism : Depends: perl:any
 dkms : Depends: patch but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: dctrl-tools but it is not going to be installed
 docbook-dsssl : Depends: perl:any
 docbook-utils : Depends: perl:any
 dpkg-dev : Depends: perl:any
            Depends: bzip2 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: patch (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 dpkg-repack : Depends: perl:any
               Depends: dpkg (>= 1.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
 file-roller : Depends: bzip2 but it is not going to be installed
 fonts-arphic-uming : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 fonts-deva-extra : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 fonts-droid-fallback : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but it is not going to be installed
 fonts-kacst : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 fonts-kacst-one : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 fonts-kalapi : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 fonts-lato : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 fonts-smc : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 foomatic-db-compressed-ppds : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
                               Recommends: cups but it is not going to be installed
                               Recommends: cups-client but it is not going to be installed
 gettext : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                    install-info but it is not going to be installed
 git : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: patch but it is not going to be installed
 google-chrome-stable : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
 grep : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                 install-info but it is not going to be installed
 grub2-common : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                         install-info but it is not going to be installed
 gzip : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                 install-info but it is not going to be installed
 hplip-data : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 info : Depends: install-info but it is not going to be installed
 init-system-helpers : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
 intltool-debian : Depends: perl:any
 kio-extras-data : Depends: perl:any
 kmod : Conflicts: kmod:i386
 kmod:i386 : Conflicts: kmod but 29-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 kpcli : Depends: perl:any
 language-pack-de : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-de-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-en : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-en-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-es : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-es-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-fr : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-fr-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-de : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-de-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-en : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-en-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-es : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-es-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-fr : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-fr-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-it : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-it-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-pt : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-pt-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-ru : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-ru-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-zh-hans : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-zh-hans-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-it : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-it-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-pt : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-pt-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-ru : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-ru-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-zh-hans : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-zh-hans-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 language-selector-common : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libalgorithm-c3-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libalgorithm-diff-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libalgorithm-merge-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libarchive-cpio-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libarchive-zip-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libauthen-sasl-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libb-hooks-endofscope-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libb-hooks-op-check-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: rpcsvc-proto but it is not going to be installed
 libcairo-gobject-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libcairo-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libcapture-tiny-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libcgi-fast-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libcgi-pm-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libclass-c3-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libclass-c3-xs-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libclass-data-inheritable-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libclass-method-modifiers-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libclass-xsaccessor-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.34.0~) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
                            Depends: perl (< 5.34.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libclipboard-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libclone-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libcommon-sense-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.34.0~) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
                        Depends: perl (< 5.34.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libcrypt-rijndael-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libdata-dump-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libdata-optlist-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libdata-password-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libdbd-mysql-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libdbi-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libdebhelper-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libdevel-callchecker-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libdevel-caller-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libdevel-globaldestruction-perl : Depends: perl:any
                                   Depends: perl (>= 5.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libdevel-lexalias-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libdevel-stacktrace-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libdist-checkconflicts-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libdpkg-perl : Depends: perl:any
                Depends: dpkg (>= 1.18.11) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: bzip2 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 libdynaloader-functions-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libemail-date-format-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libencode-locale-perl : Depends: perl:any
 liberror-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libeval-closure-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libexception-class-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libextutils-depends-perl : Depends: perl:any
                            Depends: perl (>= 5.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libfcgi-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libfile-basedir-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libfile-desktopentry-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libfile-fcntllock-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libfile-homedir-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libfile-keepass-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libfile-listing-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libfile-mimeinfo-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libfile-which-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libfont-afm-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libglib-object-introspection-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                                     Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libglib-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libgtk3-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libhtml-form-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libhtml-format-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libhtml-tagset-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libhtml-template-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libhtml-tree-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libhttp-cookies-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libhttp-daemon-perl : Depends: perl:any
                       Depends: libio-socket-ip-perl
                       Depends: libsocket-perl
 libhttp-date-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libtime-local-perl (>= 1.28)
 libhttp-message-perl : Depends: perl:any
                        Depends: libencode-perl (>= 3.01)
 libhttp-negotiate-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libio-html-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libio-socket-ssl-perl : Depends: perl:any
                         Recommends: libio-socket-ip-perl or
                                     libio-socket-inet6-perl but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libsocket-perl or
                                     libsocket6-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libio-stringy-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libipc-shareable-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libipc-system-simple-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libjson-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libjson-xs-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libkf5configwidgets-data : Depends: perl:any
 liblocale-gettext-perl : PreDepends: perl-base but it is not going to be installed
                          PreDepends: perlapi-5.34.0
 liblog-dispatch-perl : Depends: perl:any
 liblog-log4perl-perl : Depends: perl:any
 liblwp-mediatypes-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.6) but it is not going to be installed
 libmagickwand-6.q16-6 : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.6) but it is not going to be installed
 libmail-sendmail-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libmailtools-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnet-perl
                     Depends: libtest-simple-perl
 libmath-random-isaac-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libmath-random-isaac-xs-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libmime-charset-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libmime-lite-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libmime-types-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libmodule-implementation-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libmodule-runtime-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libmro-compat-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libnamespace-autoclean-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libscalar-list-utils-perl
 libnamespace-clean-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libnet-dbus-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libnet-http-perl : Depends: perl:any
                    Depends: libio-socket-ip-perl
 libnet-smtp-ssl-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libpackage-stash-perl : Depends: perl:any
                         Depends: libscalar-list-utils-perl
 libpackage-stash-xs-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libpadwalker-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libpaper1 : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.17.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libparams-classify-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libparams-util-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libparams-validationcompiler-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                                     Depends: perl (>= 5.19.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                                              libscalar-list-utils-perl (>= 1:1.29)
 libqt5svg5 : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 libreadonly-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libref-util-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libref-util-xs-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 librole-tiny-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libsane-common : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libsgmls-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libsmbclient : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 libsort-naturally-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libspecio-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libstring-crc32-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libsub-exporter-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libsub-exporter-progressive-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libsub-identify-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libsub-install-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libsub-name-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libsub-override-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libsub-quote-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libscalar-list-utils-perl
 libsys-hostname-long-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libterm-readkey-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libterm-readline-gnu-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libterm-shellui-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libtext-charwidth-perl : Depends: perl-base but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perl-base but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libtie-ixhash-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libtimedate-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libtry-tiny-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libtypes-serialiser-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libunicode-linebreak-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 liburi-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libvariable-magic-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libwbclient0 : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 libwhisker2-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libwww-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libwww-robotrules-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libx11-protocol-perl : Depends: perl:any
                        Recommends: perl (>= 5.19.8) but it is not going to be installed or
                                    libio-socket-ip-perl
 libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libxml-twig-perl : Depends: perl:any
 libxml-xpathengine-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libxstring-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.34.0
 libyaml-tiny-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 macchanger : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                       install-info but it is not going to be installed
 mailcap : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: bzip2 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-client-10.6 : Depends: perl:any
 mariadb-server-10.6 : Depends: perl (>= 5.6) but it is not going to be installed
 nikto : Depends: perl:any
         Depends: libjson-pp-perl
 oinkmaster : Depends: perl (>= 5.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libio-zlib-perl
              Depends: libarchive-tar-perl
 openprinting-ppds : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: cups but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: cups-client but it is not going to be installed
 openssh-client : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
 openssh-server : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
 perl-modules-5.34 : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.17) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: perl-base (>= 5.34.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: perl (>= 5.34.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
 pigz : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6) but it is not going to be installed
 po-debconf : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libcompress-zlib-perl
 poppler-data : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-foo2zjs-common : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-m2300w : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: cups-ppdc but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-postscript-hp : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-ptouch : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 python3-minimal : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.13.20) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 readline-common : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                            install-info but it is not going to be installed
 rename : Depends: perl:any
 sgml-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.4) but it is not going to be installed
 sgml-data : Depends: perl:any
 sgmlspl : Depends: perl:any
 shtool : Depends: perl:any
 snort-common : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.14) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 tex-common : PreDepends: dpkg but it is not going to be installed
 texlive-binaries : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: dpkg but it is not going to be installed or
                             install-info but it is not going to be installed
 ubiquity : Depends: dctrl-tools but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-drivers-common : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-standard : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 unattended-upgrades : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
 update-inetd : Depends: perl:any
 update-notifier-common : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: patch but it is not going to be installed
 usrmerge : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.32.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
 wogerman : Depends: perl:any
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Please include the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` - and also contents of the files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. This is most often a problem with mixing incompatible repositories.

Comment: After further examining it, it would seem that there's a dependency issue with perl and other packages like it (perl-api and so forth). Still haven't solved this problem yet though.

Comment: Yes. But your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and files in the corresponding `.d`) will often give a hint to which sources give problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install software--can I fix missing dpkg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474646/cant-install-software-can-i-fix-missing-dpkg)